# Passing PHP variables between functions within a class

Tags: php

I have a class with two functions, two different AJAX requests are posting `$variable` and `$anothervariable` to `functionOne` and `functionTwo`. I need to be able to use the value of `$variable` within the function `functionTwo`

```
class MyClass {

    public static function functionOne($variable) {



    }

    public static function functionTwo($anothervariable) {

        // I WANT TO USE $variable HERE

    }


}
```

How can I access `$variable` within `functionTwo` ?

Comment: $this->functionOne($Var); from inside functionTwo?

Comment: And how are these functions called?

Comment: @DarylGill First of all his functions are static so he cant use $this, secondly how would calling functionOne give him access to the $variable?

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your methods are static you need to add static variable before functions and set it in **functionOne** and use it in **functionTwo**

```
class MyClass {
    static $variable;

    public static function functionOne($variable) {
       self::variable = $variable;
    }

    public static function functionTwo($anothervariable) {
        echo self::variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the code I get the following error on this part `self::variable = $variable;`

Constant variable not found in MyClass

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {

    function foo($aString) {

        $this->val = $aString;

    }

    function bar() {

        echo $this->val;

    }

}

$test = new MyClass();
$test->foo('test');
$test->bar();
```

output:

```
'test'
```

Comment: Where is `$this->val` defined?

Comment: It's not and doesn't need to be. You can add the declaration between the `class MyClass {` and `function foo($aString) {` if you'd prefer to define them before using them (a good idea)

Comment: His functions are static so you can't change `$this->val`

Comment: Do functions being static in PHP prevent class variables from being modified? That seems strange to me.